# Disable map files on SASS

Tags: css, sass

I would like to know how I can prevent [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) from writing `.map` files. I'm using Sass in a very basic setup:

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.css
```

what parameters do I have to add to avoid Sass to generate map files?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

That depends on the implementation.

For [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) and [ruby-sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/ruby-sass#sourcemap) try this:

```
sass --sourcemap=none --watch style.scss:style.css
```

---

If you're using [dart-sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass#no-source-map) the usage is `--no-source-map`:

```
sass --no-source-map --watch style.scss:style.css
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Just for the clearance, can I somehow give this parameter once, that Sass remembers I never wanna have `.map` files?

Comment: You can't.  Just like you can't make it remember any of the other options you give to the sass command.

Comment: @cimmanon I thought about something like a config file where I can set other default parameters too!

Comment: @supersize, there is one. It's called `environment.rb` and it's hidden deeply in sass installation folder. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to modify this configuration, though I'm not very familiar with Ruby language. I'll update my answer when I'll success.

Comment: @matewka thanks! Your answer is working btw, anyway it would be interesting to know how to disable it in general!

Comment: @supersize, I tried various things including overwriting core Sass gem methods, with no luck. Unfortunately, for some reasons the `:sourcemap` option doesn't work. I tried to test it together with another one (`options[:style] = :compressed`) which worked fine. I'm not very familiar with Ruby, so I couldn't figure out where there problem is... I guess, the best solution for now would be to switch to [Compass](http://compass-style.org/). It's a framework on top of Sass and beside some really nice mixins, it has a global configuration file.

Comment: @matewka thanks for looking this up. Its good to know that Compass has this options, I personally didn't know that it is build on Sass, which makes it quite interesting to me.

Comment: Won't work for me: `Invalid argument for -m flag: 'none'. Allowed arguments are: auto inline`.

Answer (score 16):

it's works:

```
sass --watch --no-source-map input.scss output.css
```

with

> 1.8.0 compiled with dart2js 2.0.0-dev.66.0

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `sass version 1.13.2 compiled with dart2js 2.0.0` on `Ubuntu` and it's `sass --no-source-map --watch [source].scss:[target].css`

as `--source-map` enables source map and `--no-source-map` disables it.

Comment: I am using **sass version 1.23.7** compiled with **dart2js 2.6.1** on MacOs and it works like the way @ahmed mentioned.
`sass --no-source-map --watch [source].scss:[target].css`

Comment: I am using sass version 1.26.2 compiled with dart2js 2.7.1 on windows. The above solution works for me. Thanks @ahmed kamal.

Answer (score 1):

Works:

```
sass --sourcemap=none style.scss style.css
```

Doesn't work, still generate .map file:

```
sass --update --sourcemap=none style.scss:style.css
```

So make sure you have no `--update` flag

Comment: thanks for adding this, I think this will help people!

Comment: Use `sass --update --force --sourcemap=none style.scss:style.css`. --force flag will force compilation even if destination css is newer than scss

Answer (score 1):

It's now 2023, and the answers here led me to disabling the sourcemaps via **PHPStorm 2020.1** and using its **File Watchers** facility (file/settings/tools/file watchers).

In the Arguments text box, I used the following, and the sourcemaps are now history.

**--no-source-map $FileName$:../css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css**

I hope this may help someone who, like me, was trawling the web for a couple of days for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As default, the sourcemap is enabled for Dart Sass and if you add `--no-source-map` it will disable it.